# Additional function name but with fewer arguments

Tags: r, function, assign

I need to create additional name for my_function(i,x) (where `i` can be an integer from 1 to 25). I'd like it to work like this

- my_function1(x) sames as my_function(1,x)
- my_function2(x) sames as my_function(2,x)
- my_function3(x) sames as my_function(3,x)
- ...
- my_function25(x) sames as my_function(25,x)

One way to do achieve this would be:

```
my_function1 <- function (x) my_function(1, x)
my_function2 <- function (x) my_function(2, x)
my_function3 <- function (x) my_function(3, x)
...
```

But since there are 25 of them it would be reasonable to make it in a loop. For this I've tried:

```
for(i in 1:25){
  assign(paste("my_function",i,sep=""),function(x) my_function(i,x))
}
```

but it doesn't work since `i` is passed by reference and in the end the result was

- my_function1(x) sames as my_function(25,x)
- my_function2(x) sames as my_function(25,x)
- my_function3(x) sames as my_function(25,x)
- ...

How can I pass "i" by value? Or perhaps there is some other way...

Why would I want to do this?  I'm improving someones else R package in terms of efficiency but at the same time I need it to be compatible with old version.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  You'll find you get better answers if you post a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) next time.  Or this time, since you can edit your post :-)

Comment: @AriB.Friedman Thanks :) Next time I will remember to write reproducible example. Curry looks very clean and it works perfect but in this case I'd rather use some standard R functions as I don't really want to install any extra packages.

Answer (score 6):

This is called currying, and is a part of functional programming.

```
library(functional)

myf <- function(a,x) cat(a,x,"\n")
myf1 <- Curry(myf, a=1)
myf1(5)
for(i in seq(25)) assign(paste0("myf",i), Curry(myf,a=i) )
> myf15(5)
15 5
```

I guess there's an important question here as to *why* you'd want to do this.  This seems like exactly the kind of thing you'd want arguments not many related functions for.

Comment: +1 I did not know about currying (I still have SO much to learn!). Thanks.

Comment: @SimonO101 There's more than one road to Dublin.  Nice use of `bquote`.

Comment: However, what I returned above is not syntactically valid! I was just copy pasting from question.

Answer (score 4):

Well, you can achieve the same result, using `base` functions too.

The trick is to force (`force`) the evaluation of `i` at each iteration and assign your function in the `.Globalenv` (or the environment you like)

```
my_function <- function(a, b) a + b


lapply(1:10, function(i) {
    force(i)
    assign(paste0("my_function", i), function(x) my_function(i, x), envir = .GlobalEnv)
}
       )


my_function1(10)
## [1] 11

my_function9(10)
## [1] 19
```

Comment: @SimonO101 thanks !!! I love the "there's more than one way to do it" philosophy in R, I was not aware of `Curry` as well and didn't think about `bquote` in this case. thks

Comment: There's more than one way to do it, but there's only one way to not do it, and I really think this is something that should not be done... I bet the next question from the OP will be "how do I call `my_function${i}()` for some value of `i`?

Answer (score 2):

I think `bquote` will help here:

```
for(i in 1:2){
  assign(paste("my_function",i,sep=""), bquote( function(x) my_function( i = .(i) , x ) ) )
}

>my_function2
# function(x) my_function(i = 2L, x)
```

But the point still stands - why would you *want* to do this?

Comment: Well, I'm improving someones else R package in terms of efficiency but at the same time I need it to be compatible with old version. Thanks for the solution!